# no log file systemctl

Tags: python, logging, raspberry-pi3, systemd

I do not have log file with my python script using systemctl on my raspberry-pi3:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ systemctl status fourmizzzing.service 
● fourmizzzing.service - Ma raspberrypi joue à fourmizzz
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/fourmizzzing.service; enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since dim. 2017-11-05 02:36:58 UTC; 10h ago
  Process: 444 ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/mes-projets/fourmizzz/fourmizzzing.py (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 444 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

Even when my script is working after a restart :

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo systemctl restart fourmizzzing.service
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ systemctl status fourmizzzing.service 
● fourmizzzing.service - Ma raspberrypi joue à fourmizzz
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/fourmizzzing.service; enabled)
   Active: active (running) since dim. 2017-11-05 14:01:53 UTC; 3s ago
 Main PID: 1605 (python3)
   CGroup: /system.slice/fourmizzzing.service
           └─1605 /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/mes-projets/fourmizzz/fourmizzzin...
```

journalctl is also not working.

However, the code print when i use it with idle.
How can i have log file with systemd ?

Comment: 1. What does `journalctl --verify` print? 2. What about `cat /etc/machine-id` ? The only time I've had a similar problem is when the machine-id changed without systemd-journald being restarted.

Comment: sudo journalctl --verify print "PASS: /run/log/journal/1b2aaa38665b45d5a4e393ef8ecd41de/system.journal"
and cat /etc/machine-id : "1b2aaa38665b45d5a4e393ef8ecd41de
"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to add sudo before my command.
I was confused because the programm'state was printed without sudo.